# Seeing if values of a hash are the same

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash, whose values are `true` or `false`. What is the most Ruby-esque way to see if all the values of a given sub-hash of this hash are the same?

```
h[:a] = true 
h[:b] = true 
h[:c] = true 
h[:d] = false
[h[:a], h[:b], h[:c]].include? false 
[h[:a], h[:b], h[:c]].include? true
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`values_at` is the method to get a collection of values out of a Hash:

```
h.values_at(:a,:b,:c).all?  #are they all true?
h.values_at(:a,:b,:c).any?  #is at least one of them true?
h.values_at(:a,:b,:c).none? #are they all false?
```

Comment: +1; that's what I was trying to remember, but I'll leave my answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
> [h[:a], h[:b], h[:c]].all? 
=> true
> [h[:a], h[:b], h[:d]].all? 
=> false
> [h[:a], h[:b], h[:d]].all? 
=> false
> [h[:d]].none?
=> true
```

[all?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all?), [none?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/none?)

Depending on your needs it might be cleaner to write something like:

```
> [:a, :b, :c].all? { |key| h[key] }
=> true
> [:a, :b, :d].all? { |key| h[key] }
=> false
> [:a, :d].none? { |key| h[key] }
=> false
> [:d].none? { |key| h[key] }
=> true
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this creates an array to do the comparison, so it's less appropriate than @jaredonline's answer for high-volume or time-sensitive methods. It reads nicely though.

Comment: @ChrisHeald In most case that will usually be a micro-optimization, and for a hash of any size, coding by hand would be completely unmaintainable, and you wouldn't be able to do anything dynamically (without an even more severe time penalty, unless you create dynamically create methods and the cost of doing so is amortized over time).

Comment: It would indeed be a micro-optimization, which is why I qualified it. Not having to worry about memory management is nice, but folks should still be aware that it's happening.

Comment: @ChrisHeald That's less memory management than object creation; memory overhead would be trivial.

Comment: I meant "memory management" more in the "if you allocate it, you have to free it" sense. Memory overhead would be minimal, but the allocation and GC runtime wouldn't necessarily be. I've fixed this exact problem in a few open-source libraries and improved their performance substantially as a result; array allocation is cheap, but not free.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is evaluate they are ALL `true` or they are ALL `false`:

```
h[:a] && h[:b] && h[:c] && h[:d] # => false
!(h[:a] || h[:b] || h[:c] || h[:d]) # => false

h[:a] && h[:b] && h[:c] # => true
!h[:d] # => true
```

Otherwise, as Dave Newton pointed out, you can use the `#all?`, `#any?` and `#none?` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another general-purpose method:

```
whatever.uniq.size == 1
```

This tests directly whether all the values in `whatever` are the same. So, in your case,

```
h.values_at(:a, :b, :c).uniq.size == 1
```